# Is the LeakyReLU object callable?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I was trying to figure out the principle of CNN by reading some code. 
And I saw the following.

```
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution2D
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from keras.layers.advanced_activations import LeakyReLU

def Convolution(f, k=3, s=2, border_mode='same', **kwargs):

    return Convolution2D(f, k, k, border_mode=border_mode,
                         subsample=(s, s),
                         **kwargs)


def BatchNorm(mode=2, axis=1, **kwargs):

    return BatchNormalization(mode=2,axis=axis, **kwargs)

i = Input(shape=(1, 512, 512))
conv1 = Convolution(64)(i)
conv1 = BatchNorm()(conv1)
x = LeakyReLU(0.2)(conv1)
```

However, I don't understand the last line. Since LeakyReLU is a class, we can get an object after the code

```
LeakyReLU(0.2)
```

is being executed. So what does the (conv1) actually mean following the LeakyReLU object. Is LeakyReLU object callable??

Answer (score 1):

In Python, it's possible to make an object callable like a function by using a special method `__call__` which makes an object callable. [Keras implements it here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/b78e3ff9263a6c3b28c869a73f74a1fbd6fd491c/keras/engine/base_layer.py#L376).

---

An aside: using Keras examples is a *very* poor way to understand how CNNs work. I'd recommend using a MOOC or, more fittingly, the text [Deep Learning with Python](https://www.manning.com/books/deep-learning-with-python), written by the author of Keras, as an introduction.